# How to declare abstract method in non-abstract class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I want to declare a couple of abstract methods (so the implementation is required in the classes that inherit from this one) to fit my situation, which is:

I am making a puzzles solver program. So far I have 3 packages:

- `games.puzzles`
- `games.puzzles.rivercrossing`
- `games.puzzles.rivercrossing.wolfgoatcabbage`

I don't want to get too specific but in the `games.puzzles.rivercrossing` package I have two classes that represent a bank and a state: `GenericBank` and `GenericState`.

Now, they define some behavior, but there are some methods that the classes that inherit from these **must have**, like `move()` to move one element from one bank to the other or `isPermitted()` and `isFinal()` to check the states.

For example, in the last package I have the `WolfGoatCabbageGame` class and it must have its own `Bank` and `State` classes which will inherit from the generic ones. These particular `Bank` and `State` classes must implement the methods I mentioned above, for example in the Wolf, Goat and Cabbage game, to check if the goat and the wolf are not in the same bank, etc.

So initially I declared the generic classes as `abstract`, and these methods to be implemented `abstract` as well:

```
public abstract class GenericBank {
    // more members ...
    public abstract boolean move(Element element, GenericBank dst);
    // more members...  
}

public abstract class GenericState {
    // more members... 
    public abstract boolean isPermitted(GenericBank bank);

    public abstract boolean isFinal(GenericBank bank);
    // more members... 
}
```

And this looked like it'd work until I found out I had to instantiate `GenericBank` and `GenericState` objects, which of course can't be done if these classes are abstract.

So I had to remove the `abstract` qualifier from the classes.

So... what can I do? How can I declare `abstract` methods (or achieve the same behavior) in a non-`abstract` class?

Comment: Why do you need to instantiate `GenericBank` and `GenericState`?

Comment: It does not make sense to generate an object of an abstract class because it does not have all implementations. Think about using interfaces for your problem.

Comment: Well I defined these classes as `abstract` only because I wanted to have unimplemented methods to be implemented by the inheriting classes. But I do want and need to instantiate these generic classes. They do define a behavior and have implemented methods.

Comment: an easy solution is to implement those methods with and empty body (i.e default behaviour is 'Do nothing') in you `Generic...`classes and override those methods in sub classes

Comment: You have designed your classes poorly. There is no need in a well designed system to instantiate classes that have `abstract` methods. You're asking the wrong question here.

Comment: I really don't get the negative votes. You can just say "hey it doesn't make sense to instantiate an abstract class" or "hey you should reconsider your class hierarchy" or "hey here's what I suggest you should do". But no, let's fry this guy with negative votes because I can. This is the reason so many people outside SO despise this site. Some mod delete this question because it helps no one.

Comment: @dabadaba it is very annoying...

Comment: @dabadaba as @yugo - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35134038/4028085 pointed out you could throw a `RuntimeException` in your generic classes that way you can catch and handle the exception in your code...

Comment: I don't know why people downvote, but I'm guessing it's the question title. It is essentially asking for something that is not possible by definition... and some people are very "trigger-happy" when it comes to voting :-( Even though this seems to be a X/Y problem.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I don't think they even read my question because under a minute of publishing this I already had 3 downvotes.

Comment: @dabadaba Don't take votes personally.  You've been around on SO long enough to realize that rep is just a number.  The downvotes *may* be because the person thinks that you didn't put enough research before asking or because they see this as an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  The underlying issue you have though, is one that should be talked about.  As to fast votes: it happens.

Comment: please consider composition over inheritance - this might improve your OOD and you would not need to hack

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom instead of downvoting try helping him out by explaining that. This site is about helping people out not downvoting.

Comment: @brso05 Actually, no, that is exactly what downvotes are for: Erik thinks that the question is the wrong question and he's completely justified in downvoting for that reason.  Voting is to help people who are *searching for similar problems* to find answers.  Voting up a question helps make the question more visible, while upvoting an answer makes it more visible.  It is *not* to reward the poster.

Comment: @Draco18s if someone posted this question there are probably others out there searching for something similar. Lots of people probably don't understand this and will do a search that might bring them this question which will answer their question. And no you shouldn't downvote just because you don't like a question. You should have a good reason for downvoting. This site is to help people you should be trying to **help** people if you are not then get off the site.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom if someone posted this question there are probably others out there searching for something similar. Lots of people probably don't understand this and will do a search that might bring them this question which will answer their question. And no you shouldn't downvote just because you don't like a question. You should have a good reason for downvoting. This site is to help people you should be trying to **help** people if you are not then get off the site.

Comment: @Draco18s downvotes should be used to weed out bad questions. This is **not** a bad question.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom downvotes should be used to weed out bad questions. This is **not** a bad question.

Comment: @Draco18s read the site documentation http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down **When should I vote down?
Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer down-votes cost you a tiny bit of reputation on top of that; use them wisely.**

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom read the site documentation http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down **When should I vote down?
Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer down-votes cost you a tiny bit of reputation on top of that; use them wisely.**

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom also from the documentation "**Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.**"

Comment: @Draco18s also from the documentation "**Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.**"

Comment: @brso05 Thank you. You are correct. I will reverse my downvote as soon as I am able (it is now locked, but will be unlocked if the question is edited). I appreciate your input on this.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom no worries man. I just think people get frustrated when they get downvoted and can discourage people from posting on this site. I will edit the question so you can retract the vote...

Comment: @brso05 While true, Erick was commenting. ;)  The other downvotes, who knows.

Comment: I have retracted it.

Comment: @Draco18s but what I am saying is you should comment instead of downvoting. It doesn't make it ok to downvote just because you left a comment. You should have a legitimate reason for downvoting...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **How to declare abstract method in non-abstract class?**

Answer: You can't.  It's kind of the definition of *abstract.*  It's the same reason you can't instantiate an object as an abstract class.

Either:

A) You need to use Interfaces

B) Leave the methods empty in the parent class:

```
//technically this needs to return a value, but it doesn't need to *do* anything
public boolean isPermitted(GenericBank bank){ return false; }
```

C) Refactor your code so that you aren't instantiating abstract objects.  I cannot advise how to do this as you haven't provided any code regarding this.

Comment: Using interfaces didn't make sense because I had to implement default behavior for other methods. Leaving empty bodies just seems wrong. So I ended up refactoring my code. Instead of instantiating an abstract class in another class' constructor, just assign it directy to the member variable and it's already instantiated somewhere else where it's permitted.

Comment: With your solution B, I think it needs to be virtual and it can also throw a not implemented exception. The `virtual` allows the derived types to override it and throwing an exception ensures it'll be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the abstract methods with empty methods that do nothing and return the default value of their respective return type (and, if necessary, make it part of the generic classes contract, that subclasses must override these methods).

Alternatively, you could keep your abstract `Generic*`-classes and add `Null*`-classes with abovementioned empty implementations, following the [Null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: This is precisely what I wanted to avoid. Leaving an empty body or returning something random just seems... wrong.

Comment: that is why i suggested null objects, so you can leave the abstract methods in the generic classes. but since you haven't told us why you need to instantiate the generic classes, every suggestion is only a wild guess

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare `abstract` methods in a non-abstract class, final dot.

That would simply defile the concept of `abstract` methods.

What you **can** do is have your class hierarchy implement interfaces dictating the required methods to implement.

If you found your formerly `abstract` classes were actually better designed as concrete classes, do convert them to concrete classes and implement the methods, even with a default, general implementation.

You can then fine-tune the overrides in your child classes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, the very definition of an abstract class is that it has abstract methods.

What you can do, is define default behaviour, that can be overruled by subclasses.

However, I would carefully consider your class hierarchy before doing this. The fact that you need to instantiate some classes before their actual implementations are known, suggests that your design may need re-thinking.

If you're going to re-design, you will want to look at the time of instantiation - and underlying that, the reasons for instantiating.
Right now, you want to use some of the common behaviour of a class, before the actual instance of that class is known.

It goes a bit beyond the scope of answering the question, but: consider explaining the design of the code to a friend. Or to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). This may help you to find a fresh approach.

Comment: But that's exactly what I don't want to do. There is no default behavior. These methods only make sense in the subclasses (which are the actual games).

Comment: @dabadaba Then I'm afraid that you'll have to go back to the whiteboard. See if you can re-arrange things so that you won't need to instantiate these classes until their concrete implementations are known.

Comment: But the thing is there is a common behavior defined. It's only some methods that are defined by the subclasses and never by the parent class.

Comment: @dabadaba If I understand the problem right, it is about the _time of instantiation_. You could still have a class hierarchy, with a superclass defining the common behaviour. But you'd have to refactor the code in such a way that these classes are not _instantiated_ before their concrete implementations are known.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the abstract qualifier and add a empty body, or throwing some runtime exception.

Or instantiate these generic classes as anonymous sub classes